# Rewrite request in root directory is blocking access to subdirectories

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am currently using .htaccess to rewrite request in `/` directory on the basis of path

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ ?path=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ ?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

So that it can parse `domain.com/xyz/` or `domain.com/xyz` to `domain.com/?path=xyz`

But it's blocking access to subfolders.

I can't access subfolders domain.com/profile/ or domain.com/settings/ etc. 
All requests are overridden. What should I  to do get access to subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

You have to *exclude* real directories and files and you can combine the rule and make the `/` optional. Try these rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /?path=$1 [NC,L]
```